# Spring Boot with JDO

Tags: spring-boot, jdo

Do we have any support for `JDO` in Spring Boot Release Train? I couldn't find any recent relevant material.

I am looking for OSS options that can help in creating Spring Boot applications, portable to different sort of DB Engines (RDBMS to NoSQL or vice-versa), with minimal code change, assuming no change in DB model.

Answer (score 0):

[DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/) is an open source persistence provider fully compatible with `JDO/JPA` APIs. You can check how to integrate it with Spring Boot in sample code [here](https://github.com/meta-magic/DataNucleus-JDO-Examples).

Comment: Thanks for the sample. Do you know if JDO is slated to be included in the Spring Boot Release train as well?

Comment: The JDO Exception Hierarchy is built entirely on RuntimeException. The sample indicated above doesn't handle the aspect of Exception Handling for typical REST CRUD operations. Do we have any such sample? Or any resource that maps the scenarios to the possible RuntimeException(s)? Thanks.